# Avoir des aptitudes à / pour

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> -- Tu as des aptitudes **à** la sorcellerie, dit X.
>
> -- Tu as des aptitudes **pour** la sorcellerie, dit X.

Est-ce que les deux prépositions sont possibles ici ?

Answer (score 3):

Oui, les deux se disent. Je choisirais probablement *pour* ici.

[image]

Sinon, *Tu as un don pour...*, *une prédisposition pour...*

Comment: Merci, j'avais l'impression que "pour" convient mieux ici, mais j'avais peur de me tromper.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux sont possibles, c'est une question de choix personnel, mais « à » est littéraire lorsque suivi par un infinitif. Le TLFi confirme cela.

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aptitude))  **b)** [Avec souvent un compl. prép. *à* ou *pour* précisant la nature de la performance] Aptitude aux arts, au travail, pour les mathématiques
> ♦ L'article continuait par des réflexions sur les aptitudes au travail scientifique et sur la discipline nécessaire dans les laboratoires. G. Duhamel, Chronique des Pasquier,Le Combat contre les ombres, 1939, p. 129.
> − **Littér. Aptitude à + inf.**
> Encore aujourd'hui le grand don musical, l'aptitude à chanter en parties se rencontre jusque dans les gens du peuple [dans les Pays-Bas] ... Taine, Philosophie de l'art,t. 1, 1865, p. 261.

On peut joindre à cet usage littéraire l'expression au pluriel « aptitude**s** à + inf ». ([exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aptitudes%20%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

- On leur envie leur aptitude à l'organisation.
- On leur envie leur aptitude à organiser. (*littéraire*)
- Ses aptitutes pour le dessin se sont révélées tôt.
- Son aptitude à dessiner au charbon est ce qui lui a valu cette récompense. (*littéraire*)
- Son aptitude pour le dessin au charbon est ce qui lui a valu cette récompense.